# Using the Mean Value Theorem, find the values of $x_0\in [a,b]$ when $f(x)=x^k$ and $k=1,2$ and $3$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, continuity

Using the Mean Value Theorem, find the values of $x_0\in [a,b]$ when

$f(x)=x^k$ and $k=1,2$ and $3 \;\;\;(**).$

I want to use the Mean Value Theorem to solve (**). Please, can anyone help solve this? I'm so sorry for the wrong information I gave earlier!

Comment: The question doesn’t make sense to me. Anybody?

Comment: Do you mean something specific by $x_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVT states
$$
f(b)-f(a)=f'(x_0)(b-a)
$$
for some $x_0$ between $a$ and $b$. Just plug in $f$ for a given $a$ and $b$, and find out what $x_0$ has to be.

Here's the calculation for $k=2$; I'll leave $k=1$ and $k=3$ to you. When $k=2$, we're talking about $f(x)=x^2$, so $f'(x)=2x$. Plug in to MVT:

$$b^2-a^2=f(b)-f(a)=f'(x_0)(b-a)=2x_0(b-a).\tag1$$
Factor the LHS of (1) as $(b-a)(b+a)$, then divide the outsides of (1) through by $b-a$:
$$
b+a=2x_0
$$
to conclude $x_0=(b+a)/2$. Interpretation: On the graph of $f(x):=x^2$, the  secant line connecting $(x,y)=(a,a^2)$ to $(b, b^2)$ has the same slope as the tangent to $f$ at $x_0=(a+b)/2$. Normally it isn't possible to determine the exact value of $x_0$ that is guaranteed to exist by the MVT, but it's possible when $f$ has this simple form.

Comment: Please, how can I solve for $k=1?$ I have tried without success. We'll get $b-a=(1)(b-a)$ after applying MVT. So, what should be the value of $x_0$?

Comment: @Mike Any value of $x_0$ between $a$ and $b$ works, since $f'(x)=1$ for all $x$. So there are infinitely many choices for $x_0$ when $k=1$.

Comment: @ grand_chat:Thank you very much for that!

Comment: @ grand_chat: Kindly vote for the re-opening of this post. I accept that I posted badly, stating Rolles's Theorem instead of MVT. It has, therefore, been edited!